# Email service gmail-API stopped working with Error as Null

Tags: spring-boot, gmail-api, service-accounts

My Springboot application uses Gmail service, which suddenly stopped working.
we use service account, and a private key downloaded from GCP placed in server path

I could see only a Nullpointer exception , when it is trying to process the execute method

```
Gmail.users().messages().send(Fromaddress, message).execute();
```

When i debug, i am able to get the values till

```
Gmail.users().messages().send(Fromaddress, message)
```

Once the execute is hit , it fails with Null pointer exception

Log info:
ava.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:92)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)